# extract datetime from dictionary in python

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime

I received from API request a dictionary with many key:value, there is one which include datetime format.  Simplified the dictionary is:

```
d = {'_date': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 5, 8, 47, 25, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -21600))}
```

the result desire is `d = {'_date': '2020-08-05 08:47:25' }` in a variable for later using it.

After import `datetime` and `tzoffset from dateutil.tz` result can print with `print(datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 4, 4, 10, 12, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -21600)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%m'))`

What I tried to do is store in a variable, say `v= d['_date']` but it stores complete expression as string and it does not evaluate the expression.

Which is the correct way to get dict value, evaluate it and store in `v` variable, I meant `print(v)` --> `2020-08-05 8:47`.  The test is here:

```
Python 3.8.3 (default, Jul  2 2020, 16:21:59) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import datetime
>>> from dateutil.tz import tzoffset
>>> d = {'_date': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 5, 8, 47, 25, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -21600))}
>>> d
{'_date': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 5, 8, 47, 25, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -21600))}
>>> v = d['_date']
>>> v
datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 5, 8, 47, 25, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -21600))
>>> print(datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 5, 8, 47, 25, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -21600)))
2020-08-05 08:47:25-06:00
>>>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Try putting some code, so that error can reproduced.

Comment: You say you have `d` as defined above and tried `v = d['_date']` - but if you actually run that code, `v` contains a datetime. So it's unclear why you think it contains a string, unless you provide working code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I edited question and added the code run it

Comment: `v = d['_date'].replace(tzinfo=None).isoformat(' ')` ?

Comment: I tried to get a new dictionary as  `d = {'_date': '2020-08-05 08:47:25' }`

Comment: then just do `d['_date'] = d['_date'].replace(tzinfo=None).isoformat(' ')` to modify the existing `d` or create a new one e.g. as `d_new = {'_date': d['_date'].replace(tzinfo=None).isoformat(' ')}`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of the offset, simply use:

```
d = {'_date': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 5, 8, 47, 25, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -21600))}
print  d['_date'].replace(tzinfo=None)
>>>2020-08-05 08:47:25
```

Comment: I tried to store the result in a variable for use it later.  removing tzinfo this is result ```>>> v = d['_date'].replace(tzinfo=None)
>>> v
datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 5, 8, 47, 25)```

Comment: What do you mean? How are you printing it? Are you storing it in a file?

Comment: I want to save in an variable the value `2020-08-05 08:47:25`, if I do `print(d['_date'].replace(tzinfo=None)' is displayed on screen but it cannot be use for continue. desire result is d = {'_date': '2020-08-05 08:47:25' }

Comment: @dannisis The thing you are printing is a datetime object: your interpreter is displaying the object "as-is"... so if you want to see it in readable format, print it as a string. If your script "can't continue", then you will need to post your full code and let me either recreate the problem, or see the error.

Comment: it very kind of you for your help above comments MrFuppes indicated to add isoformat `d['_date'] = d['_date'].replace(tzinfo=None).isoformat(' ')` I got the dictionary for continue running the script